# How to add specialized command-line arguments in OMNET++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

We want to add some command-line arguments to run simulations. But I have not found a way to do so. The documentation provided pre-determined arguments:

```
../simulation -u Cmdenv -c config_type -r number
```

These flags(-u -c -r) are predefined (and there are some others). We want to add some arguments to run different simulations something like:

```
../simulation -u Cmdenv -c config_type -r number -x1 x1_vale -x2_value
```

Then, we want our .cc files can interact with these customized command-line arguments to do certain tasks.

In general, C++, there would be:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

I am wondering where the command-line arguments are handled or how to access it in OMNET++. I mean there should be a way to do so if OMNET++ provides command-line simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how config options are defined in OMNeT++, for example in the `cmdenv.cc` file: https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/src/cmdenv/cmdenv.cc#L63

In short,

```
Register_GlobalConfigOption(CFGID_OPTION_NAME, "option-name", CFG_STRING, nullptr, "Help description")
```

an then you can access it in the `cConfiguration` object returned by `getEnvir()->getConfig()`

See: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:plugin-exts:configoption:reading-values

This will allow you to specify the configuration value either from the INI file, or from the command line with `--option-name=value` (note that you should prefix it with double hyphen).

From your modell, you could access it with:

```
getEnvir()->getConfig()->getAsString(CFGID_OPTION_NAME);
```